# How can BGREWRITEAOF return ERR?

Tags: redis

The [documentation for `BGREWRITEAOF`](https://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof) states that `BGREWRITEAOF` always returns the string value `OK`.

Well, today I sent `BGREWRITEAOF` to my redis-server 2.6.7 and received `(error) ERR` in response.

`maxmemory` is 3G; `appendonly` is `yes`. The system has 4gb of RAM.

What happened?

Answer (score 2):

The background thread responsible for rewriting the AOF ran out of memory. The log looked something like this, repeated every few hundred ms:

```
[2435] * Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 302% growth
[2435] # Can't rewrite append only file in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Redis had gotten into a loop where the background thread was stuck, and `BGREWRITEAOF` was not able to start a new one. Restarting the Redis server was the way I corrected it, with a few seconds of downtime.